# How to keep buttons from moving when re-sizing the web browser

Tags: html, css

This is my image-button for my website. http://puu.sh/cK7Sf/6309c39cdb.jpg When I re-size my browser it goes over here http://puu.sh/cK7VU/f17dafcc41.jpg

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="Nav">
    <div id="buttons">
        <a href="/"><div id="home_button"></div></a>
```

**CSS**

```
#home_button {
background-image: url("home.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
width: 150px;
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
top: 196px;
left: 502px;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Keep in mind i am new to css and html, please dont hate

Answer (score 1):

You should not use absolute position for this. Change it to `position: relative;` or `position: static;` The absolute positioning is causing the button to shift by the coordinates (top: 196px; left: 502px;) from the edge of the browser window.

I suggest researching the `float` property as well, because it's very useful in positioning things so that they flow nicely, especially for [navigation like this](http://www.cssnewbie.com/super-simple-horizontal-navigation-bar/).

Answer (score 1):

You really should try to use lists for navigation. Here I made a quick-hand example. Further, you could easily recreate your button with CSS. So no need to use `background-image`

```css
.nav-container {
  background: #CCC;
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.nav {
  padding: 10px;
}
.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(#68B6E7,#3349D3);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#68B6E7,endColorstr=#3349D3);
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#68B6E7,endColorstr=#3349D3)";
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: With the disclaimer that linear-gradient won't work for IE8 and IE9

Comment: `filter:` and `-ms-filter:` should cover that. (I've added it to CSS, just in case)